# Prove Jacobian of $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with 3 conditionals over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is $I_{2 \times 2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

If $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$  is given by:

$f(x,y)=
    \begin{cases}
      (x,y-x^{2}) & if & x^{2} \leq y \\
      (x,\frac{y^{2}-x^{2}}{x^{2}}) & if & 0 \leq y \leq x^{2} \\
      -f(-x,-y)   & if & y \leq 0 
\end{cases}$

To prove the Jacobian is the identity it must be proved that $df(0,0)=I_{2 \times 2}$. If $
x^{2} \leq y$, then $f(x,y)=(x,y-x^{2})$. So by definition of  Jacobian matrix we got $$df(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
-2x & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

So  it follows that  $df(0,0)=I_{2 \times 2}$ as required.

The problems begins considering the case where, $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ are such   $0 \leq y \leq x^{2}$, then $f(x,y)=(x,\frac{y^{2}-x^{2}}{x^{2}})$. Obtaining the following Jacobian matrix:

$$df(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
\frac{-2y^{2}}{x^3} & \frac{2y}{x^2}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

But $df(0,0)$ doesnt make sense since $\frac{-2y^{2}}{x^3}$ and $\frac{2y}{x^2}$ doesn make sense evaluated at $(0,0)$.

If $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ are such $y \leq 0 $, then $f(x,y)=-f(-x,-y)$. And as $-y \geq 0$ we can consider the two cases before. If first case hold $x^{2} \leq y$ we are done and if $0 \leq y \leq x^{2}$ the second case hold. But second case troubles me for what I mentioned before.

Any help in order to finish this proof will be aprecciated. Thanks!

Comment: The function is not well defined.

Comment: @RafaBudría is right. There is a problem of definition on the parabola $y=x^2.$